# ggplot boxplot multiple groups of y with continuous x

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to produce a boxplot for multiple groups y with continuous x. I give an example as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(group = cut_width(carat, 0.25), colour=color))
```

I get the figure as follow: [image]

However, **the 'colour' does not work here**. 
Could anybody help me to fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it make sense to do this? Try adding `+ facet_wrap(~color)` to see the different color by groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also group by color (otherwise it will group different colors together):

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price)) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(group = interaction(cut_width(carat, 0.25), color), colour=color))
```

[image]